# pass environment variable destination to ErpCommand

Tags: s4sdk

I have defined an environment variable destination and I want to pass user/password to the ErpCommand. I use a ErpConfigContext parameter with the destination name only, and of course I get the error: Failed to get current user: user not authenticated. My destination is defined like that:

destinations: |
[ {"name":"ErpQueryEndpoint", url: "https://something.s4hana.ondemand.com",
    username: "user", password: "pass", "forwardAuthToken": true,
    properties: [{key: "TrustAll", value: "true"}]}]

The call works fine without Hystrix commands, I would like to achieve the same result with Hystrix.

Answer (score 1):

Please try to also define an environment variable `ALLOW_MOCKED_AUTH_HEADER` with value `true` for running this locally / in non-production scenarios (or `USE_MOCKED_TENANT` & `USE_MOCKED_USER`).

This is needed because the Hystrix command is by default tenant and user-isolated. Alternatively, if you do not need this isolation and are fine with circuit breakers etc spanning across tenants and user, you can also modify the default Hystrix settings when defining your command by leveraging the class [HystrixUtil](https://help.sap.com/doc/b579bf8578954412aea2b458e8452201/1.0/en-US/index.html?com/sap/cloud/sdk/frameworks/hystrix/HystrixUtil.html). In the constructor of your command, use code similar to the following:

```java
super(HystrixUtil.getDefaultErpCommandSetter(YourCommand.class)
    .andCommandKey(HystrixCommandKey.Factory.asKey(
        HystrixUtil.getGlobalKey(YourCommand.class))));
```

Comment: I have tried the second option, 
    super(HystrixUtil.getDefaultErpCommandSetter(GetMyCommand.class)
       .andCommandKey(HystrixCommandKey.Factory.asKey(
               HystrixUtil.getGlobalKey(GetMyCommand.class))), myErpConfig);   ->It still does not work and upon debugging I have noticed that the User and Tennant info is handled by the HystrixCommand.Setter so whatever info is available locally in my destination and passed through ErpConfig is not taken in consideration.

Comment: Can you add the stack trace of the exception to your question, and also mention which version of the SDK you are using?

Comment: I am using s4 sdk 2.12.0 and this is the stack trace: [link](https://pastebin.com/0FMres5k). When running in local environment, I use VCAP_SERVICES, VCAP_APPLICATION and the destination mentioned

Comment: Another detail that might be useful: until using Hystrix my service worked without approuter, now I see in the security blog that this is needed. I have a reference to a xsuaa instance. My service does not have UI and no HTTP entry (will receive messages only) and will send HTTP request to a S4 system, hence the use of S4 Sdk. I see no particular need to have an approuter in place. I am not sure though how is determined the isolation context for Hystrix.

Comment: I have tried to call the command in a JwtBasedRequestContextExecutor, but still the same problem. I generate the JWT token from xsuaa as if I would have received it from a message. My xsuaa has "tenantmode": "shared".